# How to add an additional temporary parameter to model in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model "Category" with fields: name, homepage. 
Next I want to get all records:

categories = Category.all

And I want to add an additional **temporary** parameter "url" for each record.
So I want this:

categories[0].url = "http://example.com"

puts categories[0].url   #=> http://example.com

So how to add a temporary additional parameter?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

If by "temporary" you mean an object instance property that won't be persisted, just use `attr_accessor` like a normal Ruby object.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, you want a `Category` object to have a non-database attribute when it’s passed to the view for rendering?

You can add an attribute that isn’t stored in the database, add this to `app/models/category.rb`:

```
attr_accessor :url
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've wanted to do metaprogramming, but it was so easy with attr_accessor!

Answer (score 5):

You can add usual `attr_accessor` to your model.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :url
  # other stuff

end
```

Answer (score -1):

I searched forever for this, and I'm not sure why this answer was so hard to find. It's temporary, won't persist in the db, won't be added to the object's actual class...

This is ONLY for adding an attribute to this object:

```
@object[:new_attr] = value
```

So in your example...

```
@categories = Category.all
@categories.each do |cat|
    cat[:url] = "myUrl"
end
```

Comment: Wrong. This is raising: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError